# Re-activating NSLayoutConstraint finds nil while unwrapping optional

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview

I want to set the height of my `UITextView` programmatically to fit the contents accordingly. I've set the `UITextView`'s default height to follow layout constraints I've set, but wish to change it when the user touches a button.

`@IBOutlet weak var descriptionHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!`

I've tried to use `layoutIfNeeded()`, but it doesn't change the size of my text view (as the size is kept by the layout constraint).

I've tried to temporarily disable the constraints like so:

```
print("before: \(descriptionTextView.frame)")
descriptionHeight.active = false
            
descriptionTextView.layoutIfNeeded()
print("after: \(descriptionTextView.frame)")

descriptionHeight.constant = descriptionTextView.frame.height         
descriptionHeight.active = true
```

But when when accessing the outlet after deactivating it, it throws an exception:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It seems that it is calculating the size properly though:

> before: (8.0, 8.0, 398.0, 100.0)
>
> after: (8.0, 8.0, 398.0, 954.666666666667)

Why does this happen?
Is there a better way of calculating and setting the proper size of my `UITextView`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the outlet `strong`:

```
@IBOutlet strong var descriptionHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Edit**:

It seems like the latest version of Xcode adds the outlets as:

```
@IBOutlet var descriptionHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

as @Dan mentioned in the comments.

Comment: strong doesn't work (maybe it did in previous swift versions) but just removing 'weak' from the declaration works.